# Android: fetch and save image to SD card using local web files

Tags: java, php, javascript, android, web-applications

I want to get a web page (html, php?, javascript?) stored on my Android phone's SD card, to get an image from a specified url and save it back to the SD card.

Is this possible and if so in what language can this be achieved?  Any help would be much appreciated even if you can just say yes and point me in the right direction.  I'm happy to tinker around with code but don't even know where to start or if this is simply not possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have url to get image then this code will help you

```
String myfeed="your url";

    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(myfeed);
        InputStream content = (InputStream)url.getContent();
        d = Drawable.createFromStream(content , "src");

        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();

        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),bitmap,mImageName, null);
        screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);

        System.out.println("your path  :"+screenshotUri);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that.  What is that language?  And can I run it locally from my sd card on a web page?

Comment: it is an android java code which will fetch image from your URL and store in your sdcard

Comment: So how do I call that code from a web page sitting on the sd card? - Sorry for the 20 questions, I'm a newbie.

Comment: add this code in oncreate in android activity and just run your app.

Comment: So do I need to create a .jsp web page that runs from the sd card?  I don't really follow, this looks like java to me.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have written something that does exactly what I want, only it works on a desktop PC as it's written in ASP.  I'm guessing there's no way to run ASP on an android phone?